# Activity Icon Back button

Tags: android

How i make that the icon in the activity appears as back button with arrow? 
I have searched but not find any answer.

Thanks a lot

Comment: [ActionBar `setHomeAsUpEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Up)

Answer (score 3):

It's in the [ActionBar API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) - [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29).

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) design guidelines:

> **Don't use labeled back buttons on action bars**
>   Other platforms use an explicit back button with label to allow the user to navigate up the application's hierarchy. Instead, Android uses the main action bar's app icon for hierarchical navigation and the navigation bar's back button for temporal navigation. For more information, please review the Navigation pattern.
>
> Follow this guideline to provide a consistent navigation experience across the platform.

However, you can use the 'Up' button on Android 3.0+ devices (or using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), any Android 2.2+ device) per [training on implementing Ancestral Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i testing this tomorrow, another question if anybody know a "android emulator" that are fast, for tablet app testing?

Comment: @Goodpeace - make sure you enable hardware acceleration for your emulator and use an x86 image: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Action Bar Sherlock use this code:`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
else you can use `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`